# assign auto static ip on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ethernet, static-ip

I'm trying to set auto static ip.
I've set the content of /etc/network/interfaces to be:

auto lo

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1.
```

and /etc/resolv.conf to be:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1.
```

It seems that the ip address have set successfully.
However, when I plug out the lan cable and then plug it back, the ip address is not set.
How can I make it automatically set the static ip when the lan cable is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu workstation or server? In workstation you can right click the networking icon to bring up network connections, wired tab, highlight auto eth0, click edit, and go to ipv4 settings and method manual and enter your settings there.

It looks like there may be some settings that are handled "automagically," otherwise, including changes to the file you're altering. Take a look at this site for instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html

Comment: workstation. but as I said, my problem is saving the static ip address after the lan cable was disconnected.

Comment: Did you look at the article where udev controls network configuration?

Comment: I did, I'm sorry I don't see the connection

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to that article for having the udev stuff. If you use udev down and up, the address is correctly applied?

Comment: When you unplug the cable and plug it back in, is it still the same device name?

Comment: yes, the address is the same so as the device name - "eth0"

Comment: Ok, I got it, disabling of other network managers is required